# Move txt files to another folder

Tags: php

Here is the function that is killing my brain:

```
function removeFiles($pathTxt, $pathDestination) {
    $uselessComplete= array();
    $txtname= preg_grep('~^.*\.txt$~', scandir($pathTxt));
    $files = glob("$pathTxt*.txt");
    foreach($txtname as $name) {
        array_push($uselessComplete, ($pathDestination. $name));
    }
    foreach($files as $originPath) {
        foreach($uselessComplete as $destinationPath){
            rename($originPath, $destinationPath);
        }
    }
}
```

my `$files` (old path) like this :

```
array(5) { 
  [0]=> string(52) "\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\e_12031051.txt" 
  [1]=> string(53) "\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\eam12031051.txt" 
  [2]=> string(52) "\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\ec12031051.txt" 
  [3]=> string(52) "\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\ee12031051.txt" 
  [4]=> string(54) "\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\epmi12031051.txt" 
}
```

My $uselessComplete (new path) looks like this

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(64) 
"\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\non_utilise\e_12031051.txt" [1]=> string(65) 
"\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\non_utilise\eam12031051.txt" [2]=> string(64) 
"\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\non_utilise\ec12031051.txt" [3]=> string(64) 
"\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\non_utilise\ee12031051.txt" [4]=> string(66) 
"\\vifprod1\ascii\abattage\elisa\brive\non_utilise\epmi12031051.txt" }
```

I then used

```
foreach($fichiers as $cheminOrigine) {
        foreach($inutileFini as $cheminDestination){
            rename($cheminOrigine, $cheminDestination);
        }
}
```

The problem is that it moves only 2 out of 5 files and it completly destroys them in the process.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Why not just `rename($uselessComplete, $pathDestination. $name)` in the first `foreach`?

Comment: Why are there two foreach loops nested into each other here? With this, you are trying to rename your first file to $uselessComplete[0] first. Then you try and rename that same file (which doesn’t exist any more - you just renamed it!), to what $uselessComplete[1] contains. And so on …

Comment: I wonder the same as @CBroe... You have two `foreach` loops. The inner renames an origin file, and in the next iteration the origin file won't be found. I believe that your code has a lot of unexpected and unpredictable results.

Comment: Can one of you post your response as an answer ? I am still learning and I made it way harder than it really was, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Syscall @CBroe and @Gowire for the answer :

"Why are there two foreach loops nested into each other here? With this, you are trying to rename your first file to $uselessComplete[0] first. Then you try and rename that same file (which doesn’t exist any more - you just renamed it!), to what $uselessComplete[1] contains. And so on "